# ESP8266 and DHT22 frequent hangs

Tags: esp8266, sensors

I have DHT22 sensor attached to an ESP8266. When running a sketch that read the sensor values, it suffer from frequent hangs (something like each 1 second).

All outputs are stopped (Sound from speaker or even the Serial output) during those hangs.

Here is a small Sketch to reproduce:

```
#include "DHT.h"
DHT dht(D1,DHT22);
void setup(){
  Serial.begin(115200);
}    
void loop(){
  Serial.println(dht.readTemperature(true));
  Serial.println(dht.readHumidity());
  delay(1);
}
```

P.S. it is not about the small `delay(1)`. Even if I read the sensor values each 1 second, this problem will occur. To make sure, you may run this example:

```
#include "DHT.h"
DHT dht(D1,DHT22);

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(115200);
}

unsigned long last = 0UL;
void loop(){
  if(millis() - last > 1000){
      Serial.println("#########" + String(dht.readTemperature(true)));
      Serial.println("#########" + String(dht.readHumidity()));
      last = millis();
  }
  Serial.println(String(rand()));
  delay(10);
}
```

After flashing it, opens serial monitor and you can see clearly the hangs (I put random number printing so your eyes can not cheat you by an cashed old value;) )

Comment: I have something with my nodemcu. Every day, at a random time, I get a shift in the values reported to thinger. Very odd, and I haven't got to the bottom of it yet.

Comment: @Majenko Does your setup also include a DHT22 with this library?

Comment: Certainly a dh22 though I don't know if it's the same library.

Comment: I just checked the library and it seems it disables all interrupts briefly while reading. That would explain the Serial (and other) blips, I think. It's not only blocking but also prevents others from interrupting it.

Comment: does it hang if you explicitly disable wifi (or use a brand-new ESP)?

Comment: @dandavis yes the same happens when WiFi was explicitly disabled

Comment: @TisteAndii Is this behavior the only way to make the library work? I mean should I accept it and go on. Or it could be done better?

Comment: @HumamHelfawi You can try this interrupt-driven library https://github.com/chaeplin/PietteTech_DHT-8266 and if it works, then make it an answer.